# Is there a measure to compare features on the basis of normality

Tags: distribution, descriptive-statistics, skewness

I have a dataset of cars and it has many features including 'acceleration’, ‘horsepower’, and ‘mpg'.

I am supposed to check which of these features is the most similar to a normal distribution, so I made histograms of each feature, **acceleration** was definitely the most visually similar.

[image: histograms]

But I am also supposed to support my answer by using a quantitative measure.

First I tried to use skew-ness measure, but can it indicate which is "most normal" if all these features measure diffrent things?

I also considered the Shapiro-Wilk test where acceleration got the closest to 0.05.But is this really an indication that it's the most similar to normal distribution.

The following are the measures I got for each feature:

```
acceleration: Skewness = 0.2788, Shapiro-Wilk Test - Statistic = 0.9924, p-value = 0.0399

horsepower: Skewness = 1.1062, Shapiro-Wilk Test - Statistic = 0.9024, p-value = 0.0000

mpg: Skewness = 0.4571, Shapiro-Wilk Test - Statistic = 0.9680, p-value = 0.0000
```

Comment: Hi @TareqEwaida, welcome to the site. Can you please elaborate on why the Shapiro-Wilk test is not suitable for what you want?

Comment: Hi @noe , from what I understand it only predicts if a feature is or isn't normally distributed, but I am not sure if it can be used to compare between features on the basis of normality.

Comment: I see. Then, I may suggest the [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) which also tests for normality, but gives a "distance" that can be then compared between different samples.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend trying the Epps-Pall test. It can be used to compare the theoretical and empirical function of the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0):

See : "Choosing a normality test - GraphPad Prism 10 Statistics Guide"
Shapiro-Wilk test does not check for normality. Hence, it is really not an indication that it's the most similar to normal distribution.

Comment: Shapiro-Wilk is explicitly about normality, [problematic as it could be argued that normality testing is](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless).